# How to escape double square brackets in a SQL query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

The text i want to search is `[[Help:`

so this fails `select * from tblWiktionaryPages where cl_Text_English like '%[[Help:%'`

Because `[` was a special character in SQL

So how do i escape `[` and search?

I have tried below things and both failed

```
'%![![Help:%'

'%\[\[Help:%'
```

Comment: Try escaping each bracket like this: `[[]` so your LIKE clause would be `like '%[[][[]Help:%'`

Comment: @dvo thanks that one works

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG glad to help. the answer JNevill noted says the same thing so I'd consider it a duplicate.